# Concatenar dos cadenas

Tags: c, concatenación

espero puedan ayudarme por que llevo días en esto y no me queda ): soy  nueva programando
Tengo el siguiente código en donde pretendo concatenar 2 cadenas, no utilizo la librería `<string.h>` ya que ese es el reto, hacer la concatenación sin usar ninguna de las funciones que contiene `<string.h>`. Mi código:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int i=0,j=0;
  char *str1,*str2,*str3;
  printf("Introduzca la primera cadena: \n");
  scanf("%s", &str1);
  printf("Introduzca la segunda cadena: \n");
  scanf("%s", &str2);
  
  while(*str1){
      str3[i++]=*str1++;
  }
  while(*str2){
      str3[i++]=*str2++;
  }
  str3[i]='\0';
  printf("Después de la concatenación tenemos: %s",str3);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dónde reserva el espacio donde punto str3?

Comment: ¿El espacio donde qué, perdón?

Comment: Un puntero tiene que apuntar a algo.  En su código, el puntero apunta a ... bueno, no es nada, pero es una ubicación en la memoria al azar.  Busque malloc()

Comment: Te refieres al *str3, ¿no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las cadenas de caracteres necesitan memoria para existir; en otras palabras: no puedes poner cosas si no tienes donde ponerlas; cuando declaras tus punteros a carácter (que en [c](/questions/tagged/c) pueden ser llamados cadenas de caracteres) no les asignas memoria:

```
// Ninguno de los punteros apunta a ningún sitio
char *str1,*str2,*str3;
```

Intenta darles un espacio de memoria predeterminado:

```
#define TAMANYO 100

...
...

// Los punteros apuntan a un espacio de memoria de TAMANYO o 2xTAMANYO caracteres
char str1[TAMANYO];
char str2[TAMANYO];
char str3[TAMANYO + TAMANYO];
```

Después, al leer las cadenas lo debes hacer usando el nombre de la formación, no su dirección:

```
printf("Introduzca la primera cadena: \n");
scanf("%s", str1); // 'str1' no '&str1'
printf("Introduzca la segunda cadena: \n");
scanf("%s", str2); // 'str2' no '&str2'
```

La dirección de un puntero es un doble puntero (si `str1` es de tipo `char *`, entonces `&str1` es de tipo `char **`) lo que la función `scanf` espera para leer una cadena es un puntero a carácter (`char *`) no un doble puntero a carácter (`char **`).

Si haces las correcciones pertinentes tu código podría parecerse a:

```
char str1[TAMANYO];
char str2[TAMANYO];
char str3[TAMANYO + TAMANYO];

printf("Introduzca la primera cadena: \n");
scanf("%s", str1);

printf("Introduzca la segunda cadena: \n");
scanf("%s", str2);

int indice = 0;
for (char *letra = str1; *letra; ++letra, ++indice)
    str3[indice] = *letra;

for (char *letra = str2; *letra; ++letra, ++indice)
    str3[indice] = *letra;

str3[indice] = 0;
printf("Después de la concatenación tenemos: %s", str3);
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZDPSgNBDMbPO08Rtghdt0r/3ForFLx4UA96Ee1hyMy2gd1MmZm9KD6QZx@hD7Zmty0FsQjeki/JL8mHF1hqXjVNjxjL2tirEA25y/W1Uj1jC2ILT4u7xf3zA4yGQ6WII1SauJ@9qwTX2kOIfvSy71nOjuL4N3FyECGHY1klGy/gop/ecvTO1G@oodQgamW9BtTGsp7CK6eZwAJqlt6zkA667dlpQrCrms1fhLFoACppnyM2hBbmMJS@wnnod7eflzbKJfNu4WyfziDPu2AgwW4wU0nS/blLlzKx71WncOP/4n4U2oMPLtzYsKm3nwGMbW1Ax6ijOIC0/WKQyFYuTOFgwKSz0NtYe245H03zWG@sR11S4fWKSlIhEjrBkmjGBae@AQ)</kbd>.

Comment: Muchas gracias, solo tengo una duda y perdón si es una pregunta tonta, en el for me marca error pero no sé por qué

Comment: Ninguna pregunta es tonta, pero no soy adivino: a no ser que compartas el error no sabré de qué se trata.